# Detecting if UIColor was created with colorWithPatternImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I have a `UIColor` that is passed into me. I need to detect if it is a plain color (e.g. created with `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`) or if it is a color that was created with `colorWithPatternImage`.

How can I tell what kind of color a `UIColor` is, simple color or otherwise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the **CGColorGetPattern** function with the **CGColor** property, and check for **NULL**.

```
if( CGColorGetPattern( myColor.CGColor ) != NULL ) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to check the color space model:

```
if (CGColorSpaceGetModel(CGColorGetColorSpace(myColor.CGColor)) == kCGColorSpaceModelPattern)) 
{}
```