# How to get background color or image of a view when background is set using UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"myimage.jpg")) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, uibackgroundcolor

I have set background color of a view using the following command

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"myimage.jpg"))
```

I want to get the image name "myimage.jpg" again. For this I have tried to get the pattern image using the following command

```
self.view.backgroundColor?.cgColor.pattern
```

it is returning

```
Optional(<CGPattern 0x600000364e00>)
```

I have also looked at [Detecting if UIColor was created with colorWithPatternImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391577/detecting-if-uicolor-was-created-with-colorwithpatternimage)

but it is not much helpful

Comment: You want to retrieve image name from background color?

Comment: @PuneetSharma yes

Comment: @PuneetSharma Please see my updated question

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible to get the image name.

To create a color, *Quartz 2D* uses the `CGPattern` object as a paint to draw inside the graphics context.

`CGPattern` is an image allright but a separate object.

If you want to retreive the image name which has created `UIColor` object, I would advise you to use a hashmap(`NSDictionary`) as `UIColor` object as key and its pattern image name as value. The only problem now is that `UIColor` does not conform to `NSCopying` protocol and hence cannot be used straightaway as a key inside `NSDictionary` but this can be solved by using another object and conforming the `NSCopying` protocol.

Comment: May be you are right. Please let me wait for more answers.